# How to parse a timestamp with microseconds?

Tags: groovy

I want to parse a timestamp in and decrease it as less as possible (best would be one microsecond). It has the following format:

```
String source = "2018-15-05-23.59.59.999123"
String target = "2018-15-05-23.59.59.999122"
```

Now I can parse it like that: [(see the docs here)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#parse(java.lang.String))

```
Date a = Date.parse("yyyy-MM-dd-HH.mm.ss.SSS","2018-15-05-23.59.59.999123");
        a.setTime(a.getTime()-1);
        a.format("yyyy-MM-dd-HH.mm.SSS000")}'
```

But this is parsing `123` for the milliseconds and I am loosing the microseconds: `2018-15-05-23.59.59.122000`

Is there a way doing so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to play with microseconds, use `java.time.LocalDateTime` instead. Consider following example:

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter
import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit

String source = "2018-15-05-23.59.59.999123000"
String format = 'yyyy-dd-MM-HH.mm.ss.n'

LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(source, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(format))

println dateTime
println dateTime.minus(1, ChronoUnit.MICROS)
```

Output:

```
2018-05-15T23:59:59.999123
2018-05-15T23:59:59.999122
```

#### The `java.util.Date` case

When playing with `java.util.Date` you are limited to milliseconds. Take a look at this example:

```
String source = "2018-15-05-23.59.59.999123"
String format = 'yyyy-dd-MM-HH.mm.ss.SSSSSS'

def date = Date.parse(format, source)
println date.format(format)
```

What gets printed to the console?

```
2018-16-05-00.16.38.000123
```

Milliseconds are limited to 3 characters length and `999123` milliseconds are equal to `16.65205` minutes.

Comment: Updated example with microseconds instead of nanos.

Comment: You can use `dateTime.minusNanos(1000)` to substact micros

Comment: Yes, calling this method would also do the trick. `ChronoUnit.MICROS` is more explicit and you don't have to think about what 1000 nanos converts to. Freedom of choice :)

Comment: If using Groovy 2.5-rc1 or later, you can parse via: `LocalDateTime.parse(source, format)`.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround - this will cut at an accuracy from seconds and decrease by one millisecond (needed if timestamp would be `000000` - milliseconds)

```
'${Date a = Date.parse("yyyy-MM-dd-HH.mm.ss.","2018-15-05-23.59.59.999123");
        a.setTime(a.getTime()-1);
        a.format("yyyy-MM-dd-HH.mm.SSS999")}'
```

What will evaluate to `'2018-15-05-23.59.58.999999'`